# Is it possible to consider the second row as the header for a .csv file in S3 Select?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

Is it possible to consider the second row of a `.csv` file as the headers and skip the first row in S3 Select?

- Example:

The structure of my file is as follows:

```
A   B   C
a b c d e f
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Now I want skip

```
A   B   C
```

And query on

```
a b c d e f
```

Is this possible by any chance?

Comment: What do you mean by `query on`?

Comment: I doubt this is possible. The CSV format expects the first row to have the column names. You'll likely need to edit the contents of the object to make it usable. Is it a large object?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, it did not work, the first row is always considered as the header!

Comment: @jellycsc You can run SQL Like queries on a file stored in S3 using S3 Select!